# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0 when trying to create a nuget package

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

This used to work before. When I try to create a nuget package from Package Manager Console using the following command

```
nuget.exe pack $testCoreProj -Build -OutputDirectory $outputPackagePath
```

I get this error

```
Attempting to build package from 'Test.PageObjects.csproj'. 
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin'. 
nuget.exe : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
At C:\Good\GIT\mg-alfa-dev\Test.Core\CreateNuGetPackage.ps1:26 char:1
    + nuget.exe pack $testPageObjectsProj -Build -OutputDirectory $outputPa ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Could not load ...file specified.:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: What`s the version of  Visual Studio and target framework you are using? Can you confirm the assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework' exists in the .NET framework installation folder, etc. .NET 4.5.2, C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2? Besides, please update your Visual Studio to latest version first, I can execute that command successfully on VS 2017 15.3.3. And try this command on a new create common project, etc. library.

Comment: VS Professional 2017 Version 15.3.5
Target framework: 4.5.2
The assembly exists but its file-version is 15.3.409.57025 and product-version is 15.3.409+gc1de301405
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll".
Could that be the problem?

Comment: since you can run that commnad line in the Package Manager Console, you should add the path of nuget.exe into the environment path. Could please try to update the nuget.exe version in that path? https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.3.0/nuget.exe

Comment: You were right, turns out I have a ton of nuget.exe on my machine. The one used in Package Manager Console was 3.4.x. Once i replaced it with a newer one the issue went away. Thank you for your help! Could you please answer the question so I can mark the answer as the correct one?

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: This was the simple solution to the same issue on our Azure DevOps build pipeline after installing a new version of visual studio 2019 preview - simply update the build pipeline to use a newer version of Nuget.exe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can run that commnad line in the Package Manager Console, you should add the path of nuget.exe into the environment path. Could please try to update the nuget.exe version (Above 4.0) in that path:

https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.3.0/nuget.exe